# Installing help files manually in Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm hoping that I can install some help files from a component that includes help up through XE7 into Delphi 10.1 Berlin.  I know it involves using H2Reg.  It includes .ini files for versions of Delphi from 2009 to XE7.  Looking at the .ini file, I'm guessing I need to at least know the namespace of the Berlin help system?  There is this section in the ini file that I'm thinking would need to be updated for Berlin:

```
[Merge_Namespace]
;<nsName>|<option>
embarcadero.rs_xe7
```

I'm also surprised that there are separate help files (.HxS files, etc.) for each Delphi version.  I would have expected that the components would operate the same regardless of Delphi version and so I would have expected only one set of help files.  Is it common to have different help files for different Delphi versions? My basic guess was that since XE7 was the last version I have help files for, I would install the XE7 help into Berlin, assuming that is doable at all.

Thanks

Comment: @KenWhite: that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.HsX` files are for Microsoft's Document Explorer, which is no longer used in recent versions of Delphi's help.  A couple of versions ago, Embarcadero reverted back to the older HTML Help (`.CHM`) format. That is what ships with Seattle and Berlin. That format is not compatible (or even related) to the help system that was used in XE7.

Delphi's help files aren't stagnant (and never have been), which is most likely why you have different versions of the component documentation. For instance, the namespace you mentioned is specific to XE7 (see `embarcadero.rs_xe7`).

In response to the question in your comment below: You can't incorporate HTML Help files into the IDE's documentation to provide context sensitive help either, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I also have a .chm file.  How do I install that?

Comment: I didn't understand the reason why there would be different .HsX files for different Delphi versions.  You said that Delphi's help files aren't stagnant.  But, the help for this component would be "stagnant", meaning the same for all Delphi versions.  And there was only one .chm file provided, not multiple .chm files.  So, what you said seems to imply that with the .HsX style help, the files are dependent not only on the help included, but the existing help it is merging into?  Which would possibly imply that if Seattle still used .HsX files, I might not have been able to use them at all?

Comment: Okay, so with .chm files, the help isn't integrated.  So with Seattle, you no longer have integrated help for components?  Even the old .hlp files were integrated, I'm pretty sure.  Why did they do that?  I guess .HsX files were too difficult to manage?  Thanks for the information!

Comment: @user3681853: See my edited answer. Ask the component vendor why they provide separate help files for different IDE versions; I'm suspecting it's because the Delphi namespaces changed for each version, though.

Comment: @user3681853: One of the reasons that HTML Help was replaced was that there were limitations in the amount of items in the indexes, IIRC. It turned out that Doc Explorer had many more issues, so they went back.

Comment: Thanks much for all the information.  I guess I consider the question answered.  I'm not sure if there something I'm supposed to do to mark it as answered or this is basically it.  I did give this an upvote.

Comment: @user3681853: To accept the answer as correct, there is a checkmark right below the voting arrows. Clicking that checkmark turns it green, which indicates that the asker has accepted the solution. And thanks for the upvote. :-)

Comment: I accepted the answer with the checkbox.  As far as putting the help in the third party help menu, I at least think I'm following the pattern of the other help files. They are actually in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\18.0\Help\HtmlHelp1Files.  I put a string field in there pointing to the help file, restarted Delphi Berlin, and it doesn't show up.  Not sure why not,  I guess not that important, I can open it manually. But I'm curious as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3681853: Hmmm... I was pretty sure that would work. Another option would be to add it to the Tools menu (Tools->Configure Tools), which would at least make it easy to get to from within the IDE. (I'll edit the answer to remove the registry part; as I said in the answer, I had not tried it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [Delphi7Help4Bds](http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2016/05/07/delphi7help4bds-updated-for-delphi-10-1-berlin/) expert and have e.g. Shift+F1 open the help file of your component. Not as nice as having it integrated into the global search but it would work.

There is also [CHM Aggregator](http://www.arstdesign.com/CHMaggregator/%20CHM%20Aggregator) a free tool for merging CHM files. I have not tried it but it might allow you to simply merge several CHM files into one so it will work with the Delphi 10.1 help system.